# Check if several sentences are the same

Tags: r, string

I have the following sentences:

```
sentences1<-c("The color blue neutralizes orange yellow reflections.", 
         "Zod stabbed me with blue Kryptonite.", 
         "The color blue neutralizes orange yellow reflections.",
         "Red is wrong, blue is right.",
         "Red is wrong, blue is right.",
         "Red is wrong, blue is right.",
         "You ruined my beautiful green dress.",
         "There's nothing wrong with green.")
```

and

```
sentences2<-c("Red is wrong, blue is right.",
         "Red is wrong, blue is right.",
         "Red is wrong, blue is right.")
```

How can I check if all the sentences contained in `sentences1` and `sentences2` are equal to each other? For example, in `sentences1` we have not the same sentences while `sentences2` contains the same.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. What is the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `all` and compare the first `[1]` with the rest `[-1]`.

```
all(sentences1[1] == sentences1[-1])
#[1] FALSE

all(sentences2[1] == sentences2[-1])
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can count the number of unique values in the vector.

```
is_unique <- function(x) {
  length(unique(x)) == 1
   #dplyr::n_distinct(x) == 1
}
is_unique(sentences1)
#[1] FALSE
is_unique(sentences2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
equals_vec <- function(vec) if (length(vec) <= 1) {TRUE} else if (vec[1] == vec[2]) {equals_vec(vec[2:length(vec)])} else {FALSE}

equals_vec(sentences1) # FALSE
equals_vec(sentences2) # TRUE

# in contrast to `unique` it stops at first appearance of unequal element 
# in the vec it walks through
```